# Windows 10's SSH Client can't paste tilde and backtick

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, powershell, copy-paste

I'd like to use Windows 10's SSH Client so I don't have to install other programs to ssh but it is impossible for me to paste the tilde character (~) and the backtick (`), they are just ignored.

By instance, if I copy:

```
a~`b
```

it only paste:

```
ab
```

Imagine what happens if I try to paste something like "rm -rf ~/bin" :/ (ok, just a stupid example but it get the idea).

This happens no matter where I start the SSH from (Windows Terminal, Command Prompt, or PowerShell) same behavior.

Also, the paste of these characters doesn't work only inside Windows 10's SSH Client. No problem outside of it or with other SSH clients.

I have tried in every possible and imaginable way how to solve this problem but it seems that I am the only one in the world who has encountered it and it seems impossible to me.

Any idea please?

UPDATE: I just found that the problem doesn't happen if I select the English keyboard in Windows (my default keyboard is Italian). Just to test I tried also with a Spanish and German keyboard and I can paste. So far, only selecting Italian kb reproduce the bug. But it also seems so strange that only the Italian keyboard is affected.

Comment: Are you using Windows Terminal, Command Prompt, or PowerShell in order to make the SSH connection?

Comment: Are you able to type these characters? Are you able to paste them elsewhere? In particular: are you able to paste them before you invoke `ssh`?

Comment: This happens no matter where I start the SSH from (Windows Terminal, Command Prompt, or PowerShell) same behavior. Also, the paste of these characters doesn't work only inside Windows 10's SSH Client. No problem outside of it or with other SSH clients. (I updated the question with this info)

Comment: I just found that the problem doesn't happen if I select the English keyboard in Windows (my default keyboard is Italian). Just to test I tried also with a spanish and german keyboard and I can paste. So far, only selecting italian kb reproduce the bug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows SSH uses the WSL console, which still has pretty limited support for non-english keyboards. Try submitting a new issue? https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11#issuecomment-319295853

Comment: You probably have to press the space key after each of this diacritics. I assume you don't have this behavior with the English or German layout, because there are no characters like `ì`, but maybe in Italian?! So with copy&paste you probably won't get it to work.